# Numpy broadcasting of fancy index

Tags: python, numpy, broadcast, array-broadcasting

How does the `np.newaxis` work within the index of numpy array in program 1? Why it works like this?

Program 1:

```
import numpy as np
x_id = np.array([0, 3])[:, np.newaxis]
y_id = np.array([1, 3, 4, 7])
A = np.zeros((6,8))
A[x_id, y_id] += 1 
print(A)
```

Result 1:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newaxis` turns the `x_id` array into a column vector, same as `np.array([[0],[3]])`.

So you are indexing `A` at the cartesian product of `[0,3]` and `[1,3,4,7]`.  Or to put it another way, you end up with 1s for rows 0 and 3, columns 1,3,4,and 7.

Also look at `np.ix_([0,3], [1,3,4,7])`

or

```
In [832]: np.stack(np.meshgrid([0,3],[1,3,4,7],indexing='ij'),axis=2)
Out[832]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 3],
        [0, 4],
        [0, 7]],

       [[3, 1],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 7]]])
```

Be a little careful with the `+=1` setting; if indices are duplicated you might not get what you expect, or would get with a loop.